# How to figure out maximum refresh rate for a given graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, refresh-rate

How can I figure out the maximum refresh rate for a given resolution (for example 3840 x 2160) for a given graphics card, for example [MSI GeForce GT 1030 2GH LP OC](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-Card/GeForce-GT-1030-2GH-LP-OC)?

Comment: Click the down arrow of the MSI page and read the specification and datasheet.  That will tell you.

Comment: @John I don't see the maximum *refresh rate* in the specs  Would you please post a screenshot?

Comment: HDMI (Supports 4K@60Hz as specified in HDMI ....  in the Datasheet

Comment: @John Is 4k@60Hz the maximum for DisplayPort too? The specs don't provide a clear answer.

Comment: You need to ask MSI Support for further information .

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a computer parts service.  I need a power adapter and Ethernet dongle for my laptop. I gave my local vendor the model and serial number and he has them on order.

Comment: If the unit really can do Displayport v1.4a according to https://www.vssmonitoring.com/what-is-displayport/#DisplayPort_Version_14a and wikipedia  it can do up to 120hz at 4k.

Comment: I purchased that card and indeed, it can do 3840 by 2160, True Color (32 bit), 120 Hertz 

Answer (score 2):

Once the graphics adapter is installed,
Windows lists all the modes that it supports.

Here is how to access this list:

- Right-click anywhere on your desktop and select "Display Settings"
  from the context menu. Or you can also open the Settings app and
  select *System > Display*.
- Scroll down and click "Advanced display settings"
- In the dialog, click on "Display adapter properties for ..."
  for your monitor
- Stay in the first "Adapter" tab and click "List All Modes".

This will display all the resolutions that your display adapter supports,
which is likely to be many more than Windows 10 will offer
(since some may not fit the monitor).
The list includes all the possible resolutions together with the
frequency/refresh-rates that are possible for that resolution.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get this information before purchasing a graphics card?

Comment: Only from someone who already has this card installed. Otherwise, you're limited to whatever materials you can find on the internet from the manufacturer or from technical reviews or from posts by users.

Comment: In addition, what you will probably find is the maximum resolution possible with the matching frequency. For the GeForce GT 1030 this would be 4K/60Hz (which won't answer your question).